# Ensure a tag is present and start with cva_ for all resources in Azure

Tags: azure

is it possible to ensure a tag is present and start with cva_ for all resources in Azure with Azure policy ?

I'm finding difficulty what field type to use to match for tagname. This is to look for any tag on any resource and validate that it contains a tag starting with "cva_"

Answer (score 0):

You may use Azure Policy to archive this requirement. You may use "ensure tag is present" Az Policy or "Append tag and its default value" Az Policy. Both are built in and you may select tag name and/or value durring Az Policy Assigment.